# Addition of multiple image of one product variation django eCommerce app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to make a `django` eCommerce app in which a product has different variations. For example, a product T-shirt has different colors (red, green...). For each variation I would like to upload at least three different images. At the moment, I can only upload one image per variation.

Code of my app:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    default_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_prod, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Products:SingleProduct', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT'
    RED = 'RED'
    BLUE = 'BLUE'
    TYP = (
        (DEFAULT, 'DEFAULT'),
        (RED, 'RED'),
        (BLUE, 'BLUE'),
    )
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYP, default=DEFAULT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_price(self):
        if self.sale_price is not None:
            return self.sale_price
        else:
            return self.price

   def get_image(self):
       if self.image is not None:
           return self.product.default_image
       else:
           return self.image

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return self.product.get_absolute_url()

def upload_location(object, filename):
    title = object.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "products/%s" % (slug)
```

How can I add multiple images and show them in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Update your models and Use separate Class for Image

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_prod, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    default_image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: There needs to be a foriegn key to `Product` or `Variation` in the `ProductImage`